# Edit and change parts in binary file

Tags: c, file, replace, binary, ascii

I need to change a some parts in binary file. For example "00asdd" to some number. I don't have a clue what to do. So the file can be converted from binary to ASCII.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This site works best when you show some effort on what you've done and where you are running into an error. Read up on [fread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) and [fwrite](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) to help you do the task in C. P.S. I have not downvoted you but I can imagine why someone else would due to lack of research effort

Comment: Thank you, I will do my job!

Answer (score 1):

Use an editor that can handle binary files.  `emacs` can usually do that.
You can also write a C program that opens the file in binary mode and modifies it to you liking.  Be aware that is you insert or delete bytes from a binary file, you usually corrupt its structure and it no longer functions correctly.